# How to add custom CSS to paypal smart buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, paypal

What I am trying to achieve is not actually get the payment button background to be black but rather be a custom color, so for instance lets say I want it pink with white letters (just as example), How can I achieve this?

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=#################&vault=true&intent=subscription" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
            shape: 'pill',
            color: 'black',
            layout: 'vertical',
            label: 'subscribe',
            size: 'responsive',
        },
        createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.subscription.create({
                'plan_id': 'P-##########'
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            alert(data.subscriptionID);
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

I have already tried the following (offcourse it didn't work):

```
<style>
.paypal-button.paypal-button-shape-pill {
  background: pink!important;
  color: white!important;
}
</style>
```

and because it is generated inside an iframe I also tried the following:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
   let myiFrame = document.getElementById("someId");
   let doc = myiFrame.contentDocument;
   doc.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML + '<style>.paypal-button.paypal-button-shape-pill{background: pink!important;color: white!important;}</style>';
}
</script>
```

Sadly, It still is not achieved yet. Can someone help me out with this problem?

Edit:
Just want to mention I cannot just change the style color in the script of paypal.buttons because than the buttons don't show up anymore.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only way is to check the source code of the iframe that is created and copy it, making the button a static part of your own website. It's just a simple <form>, afaik. Do this, and you can obviously style it to your heart's content. Not sure if that breaks something else though.

Comment: I have just tried it. Sadly than for some reason the buttons don't show up anymore..

Comment: Yeah, frankly I'd mark this one as "impossible" and move on.

Comment: If paypal wanted you to be able to format those buttons in whatever way you like, they would probably have provided options for that. But that these buttons are always easily recognizable to users, was likely a priority to them. There might even be security concerns figuring into this, regarding click jacking and other scams.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done. PayPal controls the CSS of the button within its iframe, for its own standardized look and feel.

The options you have for changing the style of the button are [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/pay-later/integrate/customize-the-buttons/#color); it's expected and hoped that one of the style alternatives will be a reasonable fit for your site colorscheme.